# Google Volley Structure - encoding issue in JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am using Google Volley structure. I want to add a JsonObjectRequest.
Here is my code:

```
mQueue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonRequest,
                responseListener, errorListener));
```

Then I got the error:

> Value è¯·å¿éæ³è®¿é®ï¼ of type java.lang.String cannot be
>   converted to JSONObject.

I think it may be the UTF-8 BOM problem. But I don't know how to solve it. Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: where comes the url object from? i assume this one makes the problem? have you tried to replace it with a fix value and check it the error is still up?

Comment: You need to apply some kind of conversion functionality for that so special characters will be converted into normal characters & while fetching them back apply reverse process

Comment: My issue is solved. The reason is that my server cannot receive a JSONObject as the params of http-post. Then it just returns an error message which is not a JSON string. Because I use the JsonObjectRequest so the result will be convert to JSONObject, and the exception occurs. Thanks, everyone.